# A views & CSS only solution for a previous post & next post buttons in a blog-node?

Tags: views, 8, nodes

I found the [Previous/Next API](https://www.drupal.org/project/prev_next) module that lets you create <kbd>previous-post</kbd> & <kbd>next-post</kbd> buttons, that you could put on any node.

For example, if you have nodes of the content type "Blog" you could put such two buttons under them in one div.

A core-only way would most likely include 2 view-blocks styled with some css (most probably `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;` etc).

Comment: You forget to post the module link.

Comment: And, you need to mention what **previous** and **next** stand for. By entity ID or post date or what?

Comment: I assume you mean "core only" you mean, "no custom code?"

Comment: Deleted in Edit. Yest, by entity ID.

Answer (score 4):

This you can do easily with the Core `Book` module. As you can see on the any Drupal.org page for example, [Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/taxonomy) page.

> [image: drupal.org page]

Using Book module

- You can create a Book which is like index and add the nodes in-order you want, and it will show `Next` and `Prev` as shown in above page as title of that node.

D8 site scree shot:

**Configuration page**

> [image]

**Example Page:**

> [image]

Comment: Hey!! there is a book module in core I have used that, let me just post image from my D8 site.

Comment: You were right. Anyway, listen, you say that I can insert all nodes I want to the book right ? So to make a book of all blog_nodes (all nodes of the content type "blog")... If so, how can I make sure this is automatically updated? I.E, each time there's a new node for "blog" CT, it will automatically be added to the book ?

Comment: It will not add automatically, but as you can see `Tab` `Outline` in the second image, It provides where you want to add. And if you create Blog, and at page end like in any content type, it provides the setting where you want to place, before saving it. But , if you want that, blog gets automatically place in list, you probably can achieve this by Views module.

Answer (score 1):

As you said you can simply achieve that by using views.

Configure the view as follows:

1. Create a view of **show** "content" **of type** "Blog".

   [image]
2. You can select Format as Grid and Add Fields as many you want from that content type.
3. Set Pager as **Mini**.
4. Configure the Mini Pager settings like follows

[image]

5. Save the view and the output will looks like follows.

[image]

That's it. Hope this provides an answer to your question.

Comment: Suggested edit: I guess you mean to create a view-block; But how will the previous and next be relational to the Node that the user landed in ?

Comment: I guess some kind of argument is needed for the view-block.

Comment: Bounty ends in 3 days; Clarifications would be most appreciated...

Comment: Krishna's solution is correct- the next/prev are related to the current node based on your view's Filter & Sort criteria- i.e. filter by content type: articles and sort by post date.